# Pandas: Reindexing dataframe won't keep initial values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of 5 decreasing series (290 rows each) whose values are comprised between 0 and 1.

The data looks like that:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0.60    0.998494    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.65    0.997792    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.70    0.996860    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.75    0.995359    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.80    0.992870    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

[image: data]

I want to reindex the dataframe so that I have 0.01 increments between each row. I've tried `pd.DataFrame.reindex` but to no avail: that returns a dataframe where most of the values are `np.NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/yeHdk2Gq', index_col=0)
print df.reindex(np.arange(0.6, 3.5, 0.025)).head()
```

Which returns only two valid rows, and converts the 288 others to `NaN`:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0.600   0.998494    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.625   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0.650   0.997792    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.675   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0.700   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ##This row existed before reindexing
```

Pandas can't match the new index with the intial values, although there doesn't seem to be rounding issues (the initial index has no more than 2 decimals).

This seems somehow related to my data as the following works as intended:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])\
       .reindex(np.arange(1, 10, 0.5))
print df.head()
```

Which gives:

```
            A         B         C
1.0  0.206539  0.346656  2.578709
1.5       NaN       NaN       NaN
2.0  1.164226  2.693394  1.183696
2.5       NaN       NaN       NaN
3.0 -0.532072 -1.044149  0.818853
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: IIUC then you can call `df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)`

Comment: Sure that's the intent but I can't reindex my dataframe: applying `pd.DataFrame.reindex` erases the initial values (see third code block, row 0.70)

Comment: Can you check wether 0.70 is the real value, there may be some kind of float imprecision

Comment: That was it. Printing the np.arange wouldn't show the tiny decimals. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Danche and @EdChum, that was actually a NumPy rounding issue. The following works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/yeHdk2Gq', index_col=0)\
       .reindex([round(i, 5) for i in np.arange(0.6, 3.5, 0.01)])\
       .interpolate(kind='cubic', axis=0)
```

Returns as intended:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0.60    0.998494    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.61    0.998354    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.62    0.998214    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.63    0.998073    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.64    0.997933    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because the precision of numpy.

```
In [31]: np.arange(0.6, 3.5, 0.025).tolist()[0:10]

Out[31]: 
[0.6, 0.625, 0.65, 0.675, 0.7000000000000001, 0.7250000000000001, 
 0.7500000000000001, 0.7750000000000001, 0.8000000000000002, 0.8250000000000002]
```